# CSS Grid: Fit grid columns to the widest column

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

```js
const items = Array.from(column.children)

const widths = items.map(item => item.offsetWidth)

const widest = widths.reduce((widest, current) => widest > current ? widest : current, 0)

items.map(item => item.style.width = `${widest}px`)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body * {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
}

#column {
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: lightcyan;
  background: lightseagreen;
  border-right: 2px solid lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<ul id="column">
  <li>S</li>
  <li>Med</li>
  <li>Widest Item</li>
</ul>
```

I'm making the list items fit the largest item in the list with a little bit of javascript. How may I accomplish this using CSS only?

This can also be looked at from the perspective of rows in the grid.

Comment: And they all will be same size I guess? Is there a list item limit per row? Is there a fixed width for ul?

Comment: Short answer no. That's kind of the catch, the fixed with is determined by the width of the widest item times the number of items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the UL's display to `inline-block`. For horizontal you can mix (flex, inline-flex) with css-grid, make a wrapper div with type flex or inline-flex.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

div {
  display: inline-flex;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: lightcyan;
  background: lightseagreen;
  border-right: 2px solid lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="column">
    <li>S</li>
    <li>Med</li>
    <li>Widest Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: My apologies I've edited the answer in the meanwhile, I've added grid-auto-flow: column; to the ul hence the answer isn't applicable. Pray take another look at the snippet.

Comment: @MatejaPetrović  Updated.

Comment: Thanks Keith, adding the wrapper div whose display is set to inline-block or inline-flex solves the problem :)

Comment: Can this also be done with a variable amount of columns?